# parse html using Python's "xml" module ParseError on meta tag

Tags: python, html, xml

I'm trying to parse some html **using the xml python library**. The html I'm trying to parse is from [download.docker.com](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/pool/stable/amd64/) which breaks out to,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Index of linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/pool/stable/amd64/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/pool/stable/amd64/</h1>
<hr>
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="containerd.io_1.5.10-1_amd64.deb">containerd.io_1.5.10-1_amd64.deb</a>
...
</pre><hr></body></html>
```

Parsing the html with the following code,

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(<MY_URL>).read()
root = ET.fromstring(html_doc)
>>> ParseError: mismatched tag: line 6, column 2
```

unless I'm mistaken, this is because of the `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.  Using something like lxml, I can make this work with,

```
import urllib
from lxml import html
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(<MY_URL>).read()
root = = html.fromstring(html_doc)
```

Is there any way to parse this html **using the xml python library** instead of lxml?

Comment: Could'nt reproduce with python3 and html.etree.__version__='4.3.3'. So, html was parsed without error.

Comment: An XML library (for example `xml.etree.ElementTree`) cannot be used to parse arbitrary HTML. It can be used to parse HTML that also happens to be well-formed XML. But your HTML document is not well-formed.

Comment: @mzjn This sounds correct to me.  Move this to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to parse this html **using the xml python library** instead of lxml?

The answer is no.

An XML library (for example `xml.etree.ElementTree`) cannot be used to parse arbitrary HTML. It can be used to parse HTML that also happens to be well-formed XML. But your HTML document is not well-formed.

lxml on the other hand can be used for both XML and HTML.

By the way, note that "the xml python library" is ambiguous. There are several submodules in the `xml` package in the standard library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html). All of them will reject the HTML document in the question.